# how to structure an xml file in the form of a list of elements

Tags: php, xml

here is part of my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
    <stati_team>         
                <team>
                    <team>Bayern Munich</team>
                    <victory>10</victory>
                    <loss>2</loss>
                    <ranking>1</ranking>
                </team>   
                <team>
                    <team>RB Leipzig</team>
                    <victory>8</victory>
                    <loss>4</loss>
                    <ranking>2</ranking>
                </team>
    </stati_team>
```

my goal is to display the xml file as the browser does here is my php code he work without any problem

```
<?php
$file = "team.xml";
$depth = 0;
        function startElement($parser, $name, $attrs){
            global $depth;
            $depth++;
            print"<br>";
        for ($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++) {
            print "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
        }
            print "&lt;<font color=\"#0000cc\">$name</font>\n";
            print"&gt;";
        }
        function endElement($parser, $name){
            global $depth;
            $depth--;
        for ($i=0; $i <$depth ; $i++) { 
            print "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        }
            print "&lt;<font color=\"#0000cc\">/$name</font>";print "&gt;<br>";
    }
function characterData($parser,$data){
    global $depth;
 for ($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++) {
 print "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    }
    print "$data";
}
$xml_parser=xml_parser_create();
    xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser,"startElement","endElement");
    xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser,"characterData");
    if(!($fp=fopen($file,"r"))){
        die("File XML: error");
    }
    while($data=fread($fp,4096)){
    if(!xml_parse($xml_parser,$data,feof($fp))){
    die("Error XML, ligne".xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)." !!!");
        }
    }
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
?>
```

output

[image: outputxml]

the output of the XML file is not bad. So my question is how we do so that the `<team>` tag is at the same level as `</team>` tag

Comment: You have the team tag twice in different levels? I think that this can make a lot of problem.   Don't you think it would be better to use unique tags  like <team> for the parent and and <team-name> for the child?

Comment: It seems that there is some important code missing - tha part of the code processing the xml file?

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: @AlexanderDobernig i don't think that the name is the problem

Comment: hint: Replace the  &nbsp;  by different symbols  in the various functions to see what is happening.   There is a lot more wrong in this script than you think.  Also use str_repeat() instead of the for loops

Comment: like `print $parser;`

Comment: I tried to solve this problem since 9h

Comment: See below :-)  please upvote the answer and mark it as accepted if you like it what i sincerely hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that you do not fully understand what the functions are doing. Try to look at my solution and the respective functions in the php manual and hopefully it will be a bit clearer. if not add a comment as I now know and understand these functions, I have never heard about before today.

Here is the solution:  To show what it does i have used "+" and "*" instead of non breaking spaces.

The original had unfortunately a lot of problems i fixed now. One example were the spaces inside the tags.

I changed the following things:

removed the unnecessary stuff inside the characterdate function.  This function is only thought to print out the content between the tags - you do not want any additional stuff here!

Then I added a new global var **$lastaction** which stores the type of the last tag (start or end).
And now comes the critical part that took you 9 hours:
If the last tag was an **end** tag we need to indent the tag  for the number of levels.  Thats it. So easy. But it also took me some time to get that super simple solution. :-/

I also added an if  in the start tag to remove the break if the last tag was an end tag. because that looked wrong and not like your example.
I  also replaced the gruesome for(echo) loops with str_repeat()

```
 <?php
    $file = "team.xml";
    $depth = 0;
    $lastaction="";
    function startElement($parser, $name, $attrs){
        global $depth,$lastaction;
        $depth++;
        if ($lastaction!="end") print"<br>";
        echo str_repeat('++', $depth);
        print "<<font color=\"#0000cc\">$name</font>>";
        $lastaction="start";
    }
    function endElement($parser, $name){
        global $depth, $lastaction;
        if ($lastaction=="end") echo str_repeat('**',$depth);
        $depth--;
        print "<<font color=\"#0000cc\">/$name</font>><br>";
     $lastaction ="end";
    }
    function characterData($parser,$data){
        print  $data;
    }
    $xml_parser=xml_parser_create();
    xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser,"startElement","endElement");
    xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser,"characterData");
    if(!($fp=fopen($file,"r"))){
        die("File XML: error");
    }
    while($data=fread($fp,4096)){
        if(!xml_parse($xml_parser,$data,feof($fp))){
            die("Error XML, ligne".xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser)." !!!");
        }
    }
    xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
    ?>
```

RESULT  exactly as it should be
*(the * and + are only for demonstration because they are added in two different functions so you should understand what is happening here - replace them by one or more non breaking spaces and your homework is finished. ;-)*

```
+<STATI_TEAM>
++<TEAM>
+++<TEAM>Bayern Munich</TEAM>
+++<VICTORY>10</VICTORY>
+++<LOSS>2</LOSS>
+++<RANKING>1</RANKING>
**</TEAM>
++<TEAM>
+++<TEAM>RB Leipzig</TEAM>
+++<VICTORY>8</VICTORY>
+++<LOSS>4</LOSS>
+++<RANKING>2</RANKING>
**</TEAM>
*</STATI_TEAM>
```